# Mac OS sleep - awakes right away

Tags: sleep-wake, mouse

When I put my macbook in sleep mode, most of the time it will awake right away. I don't think that there is a software preventing it from going into sleep mode. Instead my guess is that it registers even the smallest mouse movement and assumes I'm back to work.
The only way to get it into sleep mode is to take the mouse from the desk right after I clicked on "Sleep" and disable the blutooth mouse. But this can't be the correct solution. I was working with a windows pc before and there it was not problem to click on sleep and then moving the mouse without waking up the computer.

In other questions I've read that it's possible to disallow blutooth devices to wake up the computer but this would be an awkward solution for me as I'm using a blutooth mouse and keyboard and have the lid closed the whole time.

In some Q&A's people were suggesting to execute `pmset -g` which results in `sleep  1` with no additional notices on this line.

My ideal solution would be: Only wake up when I press a mouse/keyboard button and completely ignore mouse movement when it comes to sleep mode. Is this possible?